# How to add GeoTagged images to the map and store as KML

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml, image, geotag

I have the requirement that i need to add a **GeoTagged Image** into the map and save that image in KML format. Give the approach to do this task.

Comment: In which software ? (ArcGIS Java Script API or any other software ??). Please let us know the version details (3.2/3.3)

Comment: I think not possible in ArcGIS Java Script API (3.2/3.3) but possible in ArcGIS Online  web-maps (http://mostlymapping.blogspot.in/2011/08/tip-for-adding-geotagged-photos-to.html)

Comment: ArcGIS Java Script API 3.3 then what is the way forward for this

Comment: Not sure..but you can create the ArcGIS Online web-map  and download the web map template ,install it on your web server this may work. Again I am not sure about second part. It will be different question I guess..

Answer (score 0):

Check out this online tool at https://geoprocessing.online/tool/photos-to-kmz/. It's not using the ArcGIS Java Script API, but it does exactly what you need. Just upload your geotagged images and once processed you'll have them in a KML or KMZ file.